# Downloading csv file using selenium python and deleting it

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to Download a csv file using selenium python and then deleting it or just download the file temporary only?

This is the code i am using to download the csv file

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,text/csv,application/pdfss, text/csv, application/excel")

fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mention the path to your file and use [`os.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) to remove/delete the file.

**EDIT:** If you wish to fetch the name of the file which you have downloaded (I don't think selenium has added this functionality yet) you can try checking the difference in the directory listing before and after downloading the file by using [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

```
import os

before = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')

# Download the file using Selenium here

after = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')
change = set(after) - set(before)
if len(change) == 1:
    file_name = change.pop() #file name stored as string
else:
    print "More than one file or no file downloaded"
```

Comment: The problem here is that I am not sure what the filename will be, it is generated randomly.

Comment: @Chiragverma - I've edited the answer. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added one line of code and the following solution works

```
import os

before = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')

# Download the file using Selenium here

after = os.listdir('/home/jason/Downloads')
change = set(after) - set(before)
if len(change) == 1:
    file_name = change.pop() #file name stored as string
    os.remove(file_name) 
else:
    print "More than one file or no file downloaded"
```